# In AWS CodePipeline do we have an option to provide a parameter at run time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have an angular project and i wanted to have a single pipeline to build for uat, develop and production. I know in the codebuild we can provide an environment variable but if this is hardcoded each time i need to edit the codebuild.
`Like jenkins is there any option which ask for parameter which needs to inject to codebuild ?`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a variable "from outside" to the CodePipeline, for example when starting a pipeline, pass a variable 'Environment' like dev, uat etc. The [StartPipelineExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_StartPipelineExecution.html) API has no such provision.

Instead, actions within the pipeline can generate and pass variables to subsequent actions. This is useful for say CodeBuild action generating a comment which is later consumed by the Manual approval action. Please see the following links for Variable feature in CodePipeline:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-variables.html